# Is it advised to run Spring 4 applications on Apache Karaf?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, osgi, spring-data, apache-karaf

My question is literally the title: Would you advise to run a Spring 4 application in Apache Karaf ?

If not, why not ? If you do, how to proceed ?

Container, MVC and Data is what's needed. I've done it many times in the past w/o OSGi. With Karaf I've been trying many configurations, manifests, class paths and bundles. Always running into weird trouble. In the end making me wonder whether Spring is still meant to run in OSGi. If it is, what's the way to make it work ?

Hence my question for knowledgeable people. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Spring does not ship bundles anymore. So I would says spring does not support OSGi anymore. The servicemix team regularly creates bundles for spring which are installed by the karaf features. So there is some community support.

Personally I would not use spring in OSGi as without official support it might happen easily that they break something in OSGi and do not notice or care.

As alternatives there is Aries JPA which offers basic jpa support. Not sure about replacements for spring mvc. I guess it depends what you use it  for.